# grid layout with 100% height and margin in HTML 5 with an HTML 5 CSS reset

Tags: html, css, height, margin

I am trying to get a page with a grid layout and margin.

I have the code below. I am using a CSS reset.

When I add a margin to `body` it adds a scroll bar to the main body/page. I don't want that. I want the entire page to have a grid with a 5px margin all the way around.

```css
/* 
html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet
v1.6.1
Last Updated: 2010-09-17
Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com 
Twitter: @rich_clark
*/

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/* end CSS reset */


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

body
{
  margin: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content min-content;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  gap: 5px 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "search-box search-options actions" "table-holder table-holder table-holder";
  height: 100%;
}

.table-holder {
  grid-area: table-holder;
  overflow: auto;
}

.search-box {
  grid-area: search-box;
}

.search-options {
  grid-area: search-options;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
}

.actions {
  grid-area: actions;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
}

div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-box">a</div>
  <div class="search-options">b</div>
  <div class="actions">c</div>
  <div class="table-holder">this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add margin to the container?

Comment: add ` box-sizing : border-box ` for all elements

Comment: @Paulie_D but it still has the same issue.

Comment: @M.RMRF That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

the `body` `margin` is cause of overflow.
with `height: calc(100% - 10px)` for `body` you can remove the overflow.

```css
/* 
html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet
v1.6.1
Last Updated: 2010-09-17
Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com 
Twitter: @rich_clark
*/

html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/* end CSS reset */


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

body
{
  margin: 5px;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr min-content min-content;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  gap: 5px 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: "search-box search-options actions" "table-holder table-holder table-holder";
  height: 100%;
}

.table-holder {
  grid-area: table-holder;
  overflow: auto;
}

.search-box {
  grid-area: search-box;
}

.search-options {
  grid-area: search-options;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
}

.actions {
  grid-area: actions;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 40px;
}

div div {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-box">a</div>
  <div class="search-options">b</div>
  <div class="actions">c</div>
  <div class="table-holder">this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br />this content may be small in height or be longer than the page<br /></div>
</div>
```